# Random @font-face issues in IE.

Tags: css, internet-explorer, font-face

I can't figure out why but I'm using @font-face on my headers and some of them appear normal and then others appear edgy or blurry and I can't figure out why there is a difference. If you look at the homepage at http://fameordie.com in ie8 and look at the widget titled "Famous" youll see the first header of the first list item appears normal and then all list item headers under that are blurry. Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

read this: [Smoother @font-face embedding in IE 7 & 8](http://web.archive.org/web/20120310083042/http://allcreatives.net/2009/12/05/smoother-font-face-embedding-in-ie-7-8/)

and ensure you have plenty of different font-files for your font ie. TTF,OTF,...

check out of fontsquirrel hosts your font...

Comment: I had already tried that and it didn't work. Also I used fontsquirrel to make the kit so I have all the files. If you look it actually works correctly in some instances as stated and not in others and thats my question.

Comment: It sounds like you are just dealing with the joy of IE. Do your stats tell you of you have a lot of visitors using IE8. Also does it happen with any other @font-face or just with this type. Consider a fallback